# ASP.NET Equivalent request to this cURL command

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json, curl

I am trying to convert curl command to asp.net.

How can I implement this in c# and handle the json response?

```
curl -i -F file=@fileToUpload.mov -F userEmail=test@gmail.com http://www.syncsketch.com/items/uploadToPlayground/
```

and this is curl response I am expecting:

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Thu, 03 Apr 2014 17:43:16 GMT Server: Apache/2.2.20 (Ubuntu) Cache-Control: max-age=0 Expires: Thu, 03 Apr 2014 17:43:16 GMT Transfer-Encoding: chunked Content-Type: application/json {"itemId": 1908, "id": 1874, "name": "4ba6295096e940ffb70b159a908044dc"}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `WebClient.DownloadFile` or did you need the headers

Comment: i didn't try this before i need a guide to do this i used webrequest and a lot of different classes but i got error 500
so please can you write a full sample or something?